# Menu Items in AngularStrap Popover?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

Using popover button able to get menu items. But it's not showing any alert. Not Alert, Button also not displaying. Please Help.

//test.js

```
 var contentBody = 
'<div>'+
'<ul">'+
 '<li><a href="#test1">test1</a></li>'+
 '<li><a href="#test2">test2</a></li>'+
 '<li><a href="#test3">test3</a></li>'+
 '<li><a href="#test4" onclick="alert("alert");">test</a></li>'+
 '</ul>'+
 '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="$hide()">Close</button>'+
 '</div>'
$scope.popover = {content: contentBody};
```

//index.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-placement="bottom" data-animation="am-flip-x" data-html="true" bs-popover ="popover">Click to toggle popover
      <br>
      <small>(using an object)</small>
    </button>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The HTML of `contentBody` is invalid. You have an opening `<div>` instead of a closing `</div>` at the end of it.

Comment: updated the code. But its not working

Comment: Didn't mean it was a fix to your issue but it was worth pointing out as it could create some issues.